# Spring Protype Scope Behaviour

Tags: java, spring

As far as I read from spring documentation, if I put a prototype scoped bean inside a larger scoped bean, prototype scoped bean acts like as if it is also a view scoped bean. Meaning, it will only be initialized when the container bean is initialized.

In my prototype scoped bean, I have a simple property and a getter setter for that.

```
@Repository
@Transactional( readonly=true )
@MyPrototypeScope // see definition of this one at [1]
class MyPrototypeScopedBean {
    protected String member ;
    public String getMember( ) { return this.member ; }
    public void setMember( String member ) { 
        this.member = member ; 
        System.err.println( "member is set to " + this.member + ", class is : " 
                             + this.getClass( ).getName( ) ) ;
    }

    protected void someMethod( ) {
        System.err.println( "The member is " + member + ", class is : " 
                             + this.getClass( ).getName( ) ) ;
    }
}
```

My view scoped bean autowires it and tries to use it.

```
class MyViewScopedBean {
    @Autowired
    MyPrototypeScopedBean proto ;
....
    public void problematicMethod( ) {
        MyPrototypeScopedBean tmpReference = this.proto ; // to be sure we access it only once

        tmpReference.setMember( "X" ) ;

        System.err.println( "Value of member is " + tmpReference.getMember( ) + ", class is : " 
                             + this.getClass( ).getName( ) ) ;
        this.proto.someMethod( ) ;
    }
}
```

In the above case, I expect to see an output like below:

```
member is set to X, class is : com.xxx.MyPrototypeScopedBean$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$xxxxxx
Value of member is X, class is : com.xxx.MyPrototypeScopedBean
The member is X, class is : com.xxx.MyPrototypeScopedBean
```

But instead, what I see is similar to below:

```
member is set to X, class is : com.xxx.MyPrototypeScopedBean$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$xxxxxx
Value of member is null, class is : com.xxx.MyPrototypeScopedBean
The member is null, class is : com.xxx.MyPrototypeScopedBean
```

As if, spring somehow gives me a fresh instance for each reference of the "proto", be it a member access or a method call.

My code is obviously more complicated than this, but this is what the design is supposed to do. So, my question is, am I expecting something wrong? Is there any configuration issues that could cause this problem? Or this is just a symptom of a bug in some place else?

thank you.

**Update 1:**
Following the suggestion of `skaffman`, I have added the class names, at the end of println statements. Code and outputs are updated to reflect the changes.

Also added the scope definitions on the bean.

**[1]**

```
@Target( { ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD } )
@Retention( RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME )
@Documented
@Scope( BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE )
public @interface MyPrototypeScope {
    ScopedProxyMode proxyMode( ) default ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS ;
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens when you call `System.err.println(proto.getClass().getName())`? It's possible Spring is proxying the prototype-scoped bean.

Comment: How have you defined the scope on the `MyPrototypeScopedBean` instance?

Comment: @skaffman : I have just updated the question with the class names. They are as expected.

Comment: @xycf7: The `EnhancerBySpringCGLIB` part of the class name means you're getting a proxy of your class, not the class itself. See @Aaron's answer.

Answer (score 3):

Your hunch is correct: Every time you access `this.proto`, you get a new prototype. To implement this, Spring wires a proxy into the field. Every time that you access a method, Spring creates a new instance, calls the method, ... and eventually, you realize you have a problem.

So assigning the result of `this.proto` to a local variable doesn't help. Spring doesn't wrap accesses to the field, so it doesn't matter how you access it.

That means for beans with scope `prototype`, you have to be very, very careful. The best way to use them is to just call a single method and then get rid of them. My solution was to add a test case to the code which scans the whole spring configuration, fails for any beans in the scope `BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE` and use my own factories instead.

If you need stateful prototyped beans, then there are two options:

1. Create a singleton factory and use that to create instances when you need one.
2. Use Spring to autowire a bean instance after you created it.

The first step works well in Java config:

```
@Autowired
private BarFactory barFactory;

@Bean
public Foo foo() {
    Foo result = new Foo();
    result.setBar(barFactory.create());
    return result;
}
```

The second one uses Spring's `BeanFactory`:

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext appContext;

....
public void problematicMethod( ) {
    MyPrototypeBean tmp = new MyPrototypeBean();
    appContex.getappContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean( tmp );

    ...
}
```

I think you can't rely on `@PostConstruct` in this case; instead you have to call those methods yourself.

Related:

- [Spring autowire and prototype scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9819994/spring-autowire-and-prototype-scope)

Comment: Ok, this is good to know. But if this is the case, how am I supposed to do what I need to do? What I mean is, I want a different instance of `this.proto` for each different instance of the container bean. But at the same time, I want `this.proto` to be stateful so it should use the same instance as long as the container bean instance exist. Is there another way to handle this? thank you

Comment: Thank you, I will try your suggestions.